# Django 1.6 + postgres 9.3: I want the simplest possible database configuration for development on localhost

Tags: database, django, postgresql

So I have this in my django `settings.py` file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'myproj_db',
        'USER': 'myproj_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'myproj_pw',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

If I go to my terminal prompt and run `psql -d myproj_db -U myproj_user -h localhost -p 5432` I get the following output:

```
psql (9.3.2)
Type "help" for help.

myproj_db=> \l
                                List of databases
    Name    | Owner | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |  Access privileges
------------+-------+----------+-------------+-------------+----------------------
 jon        | jon   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 postgres   | jon   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 template0  | jon   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/jon              +
            |       |          |             |             | jon=CTc/jon
 template1  | jon   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/jon              +
            |       |          |             |             | jon=CTc/jon
 myproj_db  | jon   | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/jon             +
            |       |          |             |             | jon=CTc/jon         +
            |       |          |             |             | myproj_user=CTc/jon
(5 rows)

myproj_db->
```

I then run my usual sequence for rebuilding my django database:

```
PROMPT> ./manage.py sqlclear data | ./manage.py dbshell
PROMPT> ./manage.py sqlall data | ./manage.py dbshell
PROMPT> ./manage.py flush
```

and I get the following error:

```
CommandError: Database myproj_db couldn't be flushed. Possible reasons:
  * The database isn't running or isn't configured correctly.
  * At least one of the expected database tables doesn't exist.
  * The SQL was invalid.
Hint: Look at the output of 'django-admin.py sqlflush'. That's the SQL this command wasn't able to run.
The full error: relation "django_admin_log" does not exist
```

This is the first I have ever heard of django_admin_log.  Have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to run `python manage.py syncdb` -- this command built the `django_admin_log` database table.